# Use python to restart all the process

Tags: scripts, python

My platform is ROS Ubuntu in Raspberry Pi 2. I started a shell script by running python node to restart all process. However, when I kill the python node, everything started by the python node is also killed.

Python:

```
 from subprocess import call
 call(['bash', 'run.sh'])
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way to kill and restart the process in python?
2. Is it possible to kill the python node but keep alive those processes that were started by that python node?

Comment: You say "restart all processes". Why not simply reboot Raspberry ?  Also, maybe you should post your python script - at least we can understand what you're trying to do

Comment: all the process mean all the process started by shell script.

Comment: I see. I could think of a shell solution for that. Could also make it run via python script. Shell would be easier though

Comment: @Serg Could you show me example?

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer in a few minutes. Just let me open my laptop. I'm on mobile right now

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we run some kind of python script via `python stuff.py`. We can easily find it's PID via `pgrep`

```
$ pgrep -f stuff.py                                                                                         
7573
```

And kill with `pkill` in a similar fashion.

```
$ pkill -f stuff.py
```

If you want to kill only the child process, and not script itself, then we need to find out the children. `ps` command allows printing processes with PPID ( parent PID) . So if you know the parent ( your python script) then you know the children too.

```
$ ps -e -o args,pid,ppid  | grep $(pgrep -f run_bash.py ) | grep -v grep                                       
python run_bash.py           8186  4021
watch ls                     8187  8186
```

Here my python script runs `watch ls` command. I can kill 8187 to close `watch ls` and let python script move on to the other things.